# TypeError: property of undefined (Angular)

Tags: angular, undefined

I have an `.html` file where I use `{{candidate.phone}}` and I can see the result on page but in console have error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'phone' of undefined`.
If I correctly understand it's 'cause `ngOnInit` doesn't waiting for the response of `getCandidate()`, so the question is how can I call this function after it's completely finished?

Here's my code:

```
candidate: ICandidatesInfo;
    
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.getCandidate();
}

getCandidate() {
  this.candidateInfoService
    .getById(this.route.snapshot.params['id'])
    .subscribe(candidate => this.candidate = candidate);
}
```

In service:

```
getById(id: string): Observable<ICandidatesInfo> {
  return this.http.get<ICandidatesInfo>(`${this.url}/${id}`);
}
```

Would be really grateful for any help!

Comment: You can use `*ngIf` statement or check if candidate is exists like this  `{{candidate?.phone}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 3 options :

**1**- use `*ngIf`

```
<span *ngIf="candidate && candidate.phone">{{candidate.phone}}</span>
```

**2**- set default value for your model (**candidate**)

```
candidate: ICandidatesInfo={phone:null , ... }
```

**3**- use `?`

```
{{candidate?.phone}}
```